# How can i update html table row which display sql data when click button in each row?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, sql-update, row

When i click **Issue** button allows to click first row button. second row button not working.
So i want to update the table rows i want.

Here is the interface - first row only update when click 2nd row not allows to click issue button.

[Interface Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdamf.jpg)

Here **itemdisplay.php** page with ajax script.

```
<?php
include('../db_connector.php');

$req     = $_GET['cat1'];

$query = "select i.item_name ,r.qty, i.item_id , r.reqID, r.av from items i
JOIN req_items r on r.item_name = i.item_id
JOIN req rq on r.req_number = rq.req_number
WHERE i.status = 'common' AND 
rq.req_number = $req and r.status = 'approved' 
GROUP BY i.item_name ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

?> 

<table class="table table-hover" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Stock Available </th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
@$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$itemCount = 1;
if($count > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$name = $row['item_name'];
$qty = $row['qty'];
$id = $row['item_id'];
$rqId = $row['reqID'];
$av = $row['av'];


$query1 = "select m.stock_level 
from main_stock m 
where m.item_id = $id and m.depot_id = 27";

$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

@$count = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
if ($count > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

$level = $row['stock_level'];

?>

<tr id="mydiv">

<td><?php echo $itemCount; ?></td>
<td hidden><input class="form-control" name="rqId" 
type="text" id="rqId" readonly value="<?php echo $rqId; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" 
id="name" readonly value="<?php echo $name; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" name="qty" type="text" 
id="qty" readonly value="<?php echo $qty; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" name="level" type="text" 
id="level" readonly value="<?php echo $level; ?>"></td>
<td hidden><?php echo $av; ?></td>


<?php
if($level < $qty) {

if ($av != 1) {

echo 'Do not exists the available stock !!';
?>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
id="request" name="request">Request</button></td>


<?php

} else
{

?>

<td><p>Processing</p></td>


<?php
}

?>
<?php

} else
{


?>

<td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
id="issue" name="issue">Issue</button></td>
<?php

}

?>


</tr>
<?php
$itemCount++;
}
}
}
}
else{
echo 'No records found';
}


?>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>



$('#issue').click(function(){

$.ajax({
url:"./ajax/cIssue.php",
method:"POST",
data:$('#rqId').serialize(),
success:function(data)
{
$("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
}
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the **cIssue.php** Query file

```
<?php
include('../db_connector.php');

$id = $_POST["rqId"];

$query = "";

$query = "UPDATE `req_items`
SET `status` = 'issue' 
WHERE `reqID`=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo "Item Issued !";

$r = "UPDATE `main_stock`
SET `stock_level` = `stock_level` - (select `qty` 
from `req_items`  
where  `reqID`= $id )  
WHERE `depot_id`='27'  and `item_id`= (select `item_name`
from `req_items` 
where  `reqID`= $id ) ";

$l = mysqli_query($con, $r);




?>
```

i want to update any row i want when i click issue button. If you want more details about my code, i can provide.

Comment: You appear to be constructing a data grid. There must be a thousand tutorials on this kind of thing.

Comment: @Strawberry if you can provide a link to solve this.

Comment: using id will give you only first button click.because id is recognized only once.Thanks check my answer below if it helps.

Comment: @Ricky when i randomly click 2nd row issue button it will update 1st row data(Not second row). what's the reason for that?

Comment: you need to pass specific row id in ajax.rqID for every row should be different so that every row clicked have its own unique id that you pass through ajax@LahiruMendis

Comment: @Ricky can you provide some example?

Comment: @LahiruMendis Is there any ID that you pass in order to update?

Comment: So that id should be different for every row.Pass that id to your method on click.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using id of element to click that is why it is recognising only the first Issue button .Please use a class instead for click event of Issue button.

```js
$(".myIssuebtn").on("click",function(){
//your ajax call here.

});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" class="myIssuebtn" type="submit" 
id="issue" name="issue">Issue</button>
```

Comment: when i randomly click 2nd row issue button it will update 1st row data(Not second row). what's the reason for that?

Comment: you need to pass rqId for every row not just one rqid.Try using $(this).id @LahiruMendis